# WP8 Cell Tower API Information

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am designing a Windows Phone 8 app and I have been researching location API. However I am only seeing location services for GPS. I don't really want to use GPS for my location app, I only need to a broad cell tower information. I would like to use the cell tower ID and any other information the API comes back with.

Would it be possible to obtain this information currently with the WP8 API?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this capability is not currently available in the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: I was just writing a similar SO question of my own when I saw this! What about wifi? Is there any way to access identifying information about the currently connected wireless network, e.g. its SSID, mac address, or similar?

Comment: No, you will not be able to do that through the official SDK.